# how to EXEC a multiline SELECT?

Tags: sql, t-sql

The following `exec` is generating this exception:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '
with
cte_rag as
(select
 rc.RagColumnId
,rc.RagId
,rc.Header
,rc.FormElementId
,rc.BaseObjectColumnName
,b.BaseObjectTy'.

Completion time: 2021-11-29T12:58:41.5681063-06:00
```

Here's the full sql:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
set @sql = '''
with
cte_rag as
(select
 rc.RagColumnId
,rc.RagId
,rc.Header
,rc.FormElementId
,rc.BaseObjectColumnName
,b.BaseObjectTypeId
,b.BaseObjectTypeName
,b.TableName
from rag.rags r
join rag.RagColumns rc
on r.RagId = rc.ragid
join rag.BaseObjectTypes b
on r.BaseObjectTypeId = b.BaseObjectTypeId
),
cte_scalar_data (projectid,formdataid,formlementid,displayvalue) as (
SELECT
    p.ProjectId,
    fd.formdataid,
    t.FormElementId,
    (CASE
            WHEN t.FormDataAdapterId IS NOT NULL
            THEN dbo.GetFormDataAdapterValue(t.FormDataAdapterId, se.Value)
            ELSE
                ISNULL(
                CASE WHEN t.FormElementTypeId IN (4,5)
                THEN
                    dbo.GetOptionCaption(t.FormElementId, se.Value)
                ELSE
                    CASE WHEN t.FormElementTypeId = 3
                    THEN
                        FORMAT(CONVERT([datetime], se.Value), ''yyyy-MM-dd'')
                    ELSE
                        CASE WHEN t.FormElementTypeId = 7
                        THEN
                            se.Value2
                        ELSE
                            se.Value
                        END
                    END
                END, t.OptionCaption)
        END) AS DisplayValue
FROM
    Projects p
    INNER JOIN FormData fd ON fd.ObjectId = p.ProjectId
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        e.FormId,
        e.FormElementId,
        e.FormElementTypeId,
        e.Name,
        e.Title,
        da.FormDataAdapterId,
        e.Title AS ValueName,
        o.Caption AS OptionCaption,
        e.PermanentName
    FROM
        FormElements e
        LEFT JOIN FormElementDataAdapters da ON e.FormElementId = da.FormElementId
        LEFT JOIN FormElementOptions o ON o.FormElementId = e.FormElementId AND o.IsDefault = 1
    WHERE e.FormElementId IS NOT NULL AND e.FormElementTypeId IN (1,3,4,5,7) ) t
    ON t.FormId = fd.FormId
    LEFT JOIN FormScalarElementsData se ON fd.FormDataId = se.FormDataId AND t.FormElementId = se.FormElementId
)

select r.header
      ,r.FormElementId
      ,r.BaseObjectColumnName
      ,r.BaseObjectTypeName
      ,fe.FormId
      ,fd.ObjectId
      ,p.projectid
      ,c.cipid
      ,fd.FormDataId
      ,cs.displayvalue
from cte_rag r
left join formelements fe
on fe.FormElementId = r.FormElementId
left join formdata fd
on fd.FormId = fe.FormId
left join dbo.projects p
on fd.objectid = p.projectid
left join dbo.cips c
on fd.objectid = c.CipId
left join cte_scalar_data cs
on      cs.formdataid = fd.FormDataId
    and cs.formlementid = r.FormElementId
    and cs.projectid = p.ProjectId
    '''

    exec(@sql)
```

**What am I doing wrong? How do we run this `exec` command?**

Comment: Single quotes already respect multiple lines. If it didn't and the triple `'''` syntax worked, then you wouldn't need to escape the single quotes like you have with your literal `''yyyy-MM-dd''`. Why are you using `EXEC(@SQL)` at all here though? Normally that would be for dynamic SQL, but there's nothing dynamic about your SQL. *(It's also highly recommended you use `sys.sp_executesql` to execute SQL strings, as it can be parametrised, where as `EXEC (@SQL)` cannot.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL has too many quotes added at the start and end, you don't need to encase the dynamic SQL in its own quotes, remove the `'''` at the start and end, just simply do

```
set @sql = '
with
cte_rag as...
...
and cs.projectid = p.ProjectId
'
```